# Developing Eclipse Plugin with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin

I personally prefer the IntelliJ IDEA to develop in Java, but I need to create an Eclipse Plugin for a customer.

Is it possible to develop Eclipse plugins in IDEA? Does anyone have any experience with that kind of thing?

Comment: @greg449 Dude, this doesn't help me at all, thanks anyways for your comment...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need just the same )

Comment: @NickVolynkin Unfortunately: No ...